# Spring Cloud/Security how to do something useful with a JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, auth0

Using Auth0 I can receive and authenticate with a JWT. This was as simple as adding

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value(value = "${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value(value = "${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable();

        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                .forRS256(audience, issuer)
                .configure(http)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is where/how do I do something with each request such as saving the users details to a database, or say attach the user to a POJO for a relationship use?

Once I've got that user details saved somewhere, how do I do things with it such as get all the objects that belong to this user (assuming I've saved that against the user POJO) on each request?

I'm fresh to Spring so struggling with finding the correct resources for this workflow that don't go off on some adventure of creating and signing their own tokens...

Comment: So obviously you must be using Spring Rest/ Spring Data as well?.. So have you defined your controller endpoints / setup db access ? Or are you asking how to do this? ... If you have already done this, one option is to add another Aspect for each @RestController. other is to declare a super class for all the controllers and do the user extraction for each request in there. Please clarify!

Comment: Correct on spring rest/data. If for example I want to make sure a user is only returning data that belongs to them via a generic rest request how would I go about such a thing? Surely I don't want to be adding a Principle to each and every rest param, then checking against a database for example on every end point? Or do I?

Comment: The SecurityContextHolder holds our authenticated principle for each request and can be accessed anywhere since it is in a static context. `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` You can maybe extend all your controllers and write a util like getCredentials(). Which returns the principle. This is of course if you want attach it with your pojo. For auditing purposes you can automate this by writing a login filter. Is this what you want?